Hide MSIX package from "Installed Apps" list
Is there a way to craft or install an MSIX package so it doesn't appear in Windows 11's "Installed apps" list?
We have an app that uses a non-MSIX installer, but the shell extension has to be packaged in an MSIX on Windows 11.  Right now we're packaging just the extension as a standalone package and the outer installer uses PowerShell's Add-AppxPackage or Add-AppProvisionedPackage.  That results in two entries, AppName and AppName Shell Extension, which can confuse our end users.
PowerShell's Set-NonRemovableAppsPolicy keeps it from being removed, but it still shows in the list, and the error message is obtuse.
Adding uap10:AllowExternalContent to the msix manifest does hide it (and would be preferable), but if we do that Add-AppProvisionedPackage gives a "The request is unsupported" error, so it isn't usable for machine-wide installs.
TortoiseSVN/Git have to do the same thing, and AFAICT they just use uap10:AllowExternalContent, only install the MSIX for the installing user, and rely on a button in their Options dialogs to let other users on the computer manually install the subpackage.
